# Prevent Page from reloading after AJAX PUT Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to prevent my page from reloading after an Ajax PUT Request.

Basically i have a PUT request to update my database which is fired from a button click, on success of this i want to call another function which is an ajax GET, to reload the data i have just updated, However when doing this, i hit the controller method and get the new list of data, but the page reloads to default and does nothing with my new list

**Ajax PUT**

```
function SendDeleteToController(checkid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '@Url.Action("PutCheck", "Admin")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: JSON,
        data: JSON.stringify({ methodParam: checkid }),
        success: function () {
            GetListofChecks();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
```

**AJAX GET**

```
function GetListofChecks() {
    var department = $('#department').val();
    var process = $('#process').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetListofChecks", "Admin")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: JSON,
        data: { "Department": department, "Process": process },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#mainData").empty();

            $.each(JSON.parse(result),
                function (i, item) {
                    var row = i + 1;
                    $("#mainData").append()
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**controller that returns list of new data**

```
public JsonResult GetListofChecks(string department, string process)
{
    var listofChecks = new List<Check>();

    listofChecks = AdminModel.GetListofchecks(department, process);

    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listofChecks);
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You dont need a GET request to return the data, just return the data in your PUT request and append it to your document using the success callback handler

Comment: FYI, you don't need to do this `var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listofChecks);` instead just do this `return Json(listofChecks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use another request (`GET`) to retrieve the data, just return it in your controller after you delete the item, the callback function will get a response object for use in your `success/error` callback functions

Try this (comments in code):

```
function SendDeleteToController(checkid){
  $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: '@Url.Action("PutCheck", "Admin")',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      datatype: JSON,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        methodParam: checkid
      }),
      success: function(result) {
        //your request will return the json object for use in your callback function
        //something like below, though I dont know what your JSON result looks like
        $('body').append(result.id);
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert("error " + result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have tried

```
 function SendDeleteToController(checkid) {


    var department = $('#department').val();
    var process = $('#process').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '@Url.Action("PutCheck", "Admin")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: JSON,
        data: JSON.stringify({ID: checkid, Department: department, Process: process}),
        success: function (result) {

            $("#mainData").empty();

            debugger;

            $.each(JSON.parse(result),
                function (i, item)
                {
                    var row = i + 1;

                    $("#mainData").append(
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<td id='application" + row + "'" + ">" + item.Application + "</td>" +

                        "<td id='department" + row + "'" + ">" + item.Department + "</td>" +

                        "<td id='process" + row + "'" + ">" + item.Process + "</td>" +

                        "<td id='checks" + row + "'" + ">" + item.Checks + "</td>" +

                        "<td id='Action" + row + "'" +">" +
                        "<button id='test' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger " +
                        "'" + "onclick='DeleteProcess(" + item.Id + ")" +
                        "'" + ">" + "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash" +
                        "'" + "></i>" + "</button>" + "&nbsp" +

                        "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary " +"'" +
                        "onclick='EditProcess(" + item.Id + ")" +
                        "'" + ">" +
                        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" + "'" + "></i>" +
                        "</button>" +
                        "</td>" + "</tr>");
                });
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error " + result);
        }
    });
}
```

updated controller

```
    [HttpPut]
    public JsonResult PutCheck(string ID, string department, string process)
    {
        var checkId = ID;
        var listofChecks = new List<Check>();

        if (checkId != null)
        {

            // delete data
            AdminModel.DeleteCheck(checkId);

            // get update list of data
            listofChecks = AdminModel.GetListofchecks(department, process);

        }

        return Json(listofChecks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be the answer to you question, or just some other code your tried and still does not work? If so edit you question and delete this (this section is for **answers**)